# java.lang.NullPointerException in login using sqlite

Tags: android, authentication, nullpointerexception, android-sqlite

I am trying to login using the `phone_no` and `password` but its giving `NullPointerException` when I'm using this :

```
Cursor cursor=db.query("CitizenDetails", null, "phone=?", new String[]{phone}, null, null, null);
```

Where is it going wrong? My head is paining trying to figure this out for hours thanks.

Logcat :

```
02-27 12:10:58.783: E/AndroidRuntime(6586): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-27 12:10:58.783: E/AndroidRuntime(6586): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-27 12:10:58.783: E/AndroidRuntime(6586):     at com.example.customdialogregistration.DatabaseHelper.getSinlgeEntry(DatabaseHelper.java:200)
02-27 12:10:58.783: E/AndroidRuntime(6586):     at com.example.customdialogregistration.MainActivity$1$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:75)
02-27 12:10:58.783: E/AndroidRuntime(6586):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
02-27 12:10:58.783: E/AndroidRuntime(6586):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
02-27 12:10:58.783: E/AndroidRuntime(6586):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
02-27 12:10:58.783: E/AndroidRuntime(6586):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-27 12:10:58.783: E/AndroidRuntime(6586):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-27 12:10:58.783: E/AndroidRuntime(6586):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
02-27 12:10:58.783: E/AndroidRuntime(6586):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-27 12:10:58.783: E/AndroidRuntime(6586):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-27 12:10:58.783: E/AndroidRuntime(6586):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-27 12:10:58.783: E/AndroidRuntime(6586):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-27 12:10:58.783: E/AndroidRuntime(6586):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you initialize this line before

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
```

Answer (score 0):

That row can NPE only if `db` is `null`.